# Asterisk12 and sipML5 video support

Tags: video, asterisk, rtp, vp8

is it possible to send video each other on asterisk12 and sipML5 demo site?
I can hear audio but video is black screen...
I set sip.conf like this,

```
[general]
videosupport=yes
[6001]
host=dynamic
secret=1234
context=from-internal
type=friend
encryption=yes
avpf=yes
force_avp=yes
icesupport=yes
directmedia=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
allow=h261
allow=h263
allow=h264
allow=vp8
dtlsenable=yes
dtlsverify=fingerprint
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
dtlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
dtlssetup=actpass

[6002]
host=dynamic
secret=1234
context=from-internal
type=friend
encryption=yes
avpf=yes
force_avp=yes
icesupport=yes
directmedia=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
allow=h261
allow=h263
allow=h264
allow=vp8
dtlsenable=yes
dtlsverify=fingerprint
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
dtlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
dtlssetup=actpass
```

my environment,
sipml5 demo site
http://sipml5.org/call.htm?svn=224

asterisk
Asterisk 12.4.0 built by root @ 48asterisk on a x86_64 running Linux on 2014-08-01 08:22:18 UTC

OS
debian 7.6

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- in asterisk you should allow only ONE video codec for each peer e.g:

disallow=all

allow=h263

as asterisk does not support video codec negotiation!
2-you'd better use webrtc2sip (http://webrtc2sip.org/) between sipml5 and asterisk. it solves protocol negotiation issues such as SRTP and ICE are mandatory in webrtc specification. it also does codec conversion between multiple browsers.

i have set a sipml5-webrtc2sip-asterisk structure and it works very fine!! :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was able to watch video!!

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you have enabled websocket in http.conf and configure sipml to point to your WS [here](http://sipml5.org/expert.htm). Plus, your peers aren't configured with ws transport type.

If you follow [this](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/WebRTC+tutorial+using+SIPML5) guide step by step it'll all work...